# Assign value to the first m elements of an array of size n in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration

I have an array declared in the global scope (outside the `main()` function) of size `n`, and inside the `main()` I need to assign it the first `m` (`m < n`) values. How do I approach this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int array[50];

int main()
{
    array = {1,2,3,4,5};  //can not execute, error
    return 0;
}
```

---

The error I am getting:

> ```
> assigning to an array from an initializer list
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to initialize the array with some initial values, you have to do this immediately with the initialization, not after the initialization.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   int array[50] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   return 0;
}
```

But, if you really need to copy values, the easiest way is to copy values one by one.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int array[50];

int main(){
   int temp[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
       array[i] = temp[i];
   return 0;
}
```